# Why is the additive identity of a Quotient Space the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

I am reading Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition.

Say, we have a subspace $U$ of vector space $V$.
The book says that a quotient space is defined by 
$V/U = \{v + U: v \in U \}$

It then says that the additive identity of $V/U$ is $0+U$ and the additive inverse is $-v + U$. I didn't understand how the additive identity and additive inverse is that.

Comment: Let $e$ be the additive identity, then,

$$(v+U)* e = v+U \implies \forall\ u, v \in U, \exists \ u' \in U \ \text{ s.t. } \ v+u + e = v+u' \\ \implies e = 0 + u-u' = 0 + u'' \implies e = 0 + U$$

Note that there will always exists $u'' \in U$ s.t. $u-u' = u''$ because $U$ is a subspace (closed under addition).

Similarly, workout the additive inverse.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand: what is meant by expressions "$0+U$" and "$-v+U$", or why it's true that they are the identity and the inverse in the quotient space? Those are two different questions.